# use sed awk to replace variable defined in another file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a users.txt file in the format:

```
User:CityID
Carl:0212
Syd:0312
Rick:9323
```

and a city.txt file in the format

```
Anaheim:0212
San Jose:0312
```

I need to replace every CityID in the users.txt with the city name from the city.txt file.
How can I achieve this using sed and awk?

I can get the column of CityID's using awk using:

```
awk -F$'\:' '{print $2}'< users.txt
```

but how do it replace them with the corresponding city name?

Thank you.

Comment: When you redirect input from a file `awk '...' < file`, you lose the ability for awk to populate the often-useful `FILENAME` variable. Just let awk open the file itself `awk '...' file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{$2=a[$2]}1' city.txt user.txt
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}` : We set the Input and Output Field Separator to `:`
- `NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}` : We read the city file and create an array to store City Name indexed at City ID
- `{$2=a[$2]}` : We replace the second field in user.txt by referencing the array
- `1` : This is to print the line

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` to transform `city.txt` into a `sed` script:

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/s%\2%\1%g/' city.txt
```

then feed that to a second `sed` instance to process `users.txt`:

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/s%\2%\1%g/' city.txt |
sed -f - users.txt
```

Not all `sed` variants will accept a script file on standard input; you'll have to resort to a temporary file in that case.

Comment: +1 for this approach, but may has a bug, that can't identify some IDs, such as `0212` and `02120`

Comment: One could elaborate the generated script with word or field boundary markers, but given the sample data (fixed field length with leading zero padding) that didn't seem necessary. A quick and dirty fix would be `s%:\2$%:\1%`